Use os_log_default in Metal
I want to do logging from a .metal file.
From the specification:

Metal defines the logging functions and types in <metal_logging>. To enable logging, you need to set -fmetal-enable-logging (see section 1.6.9).

I made a simple shader with a log
#include <metal_stdlib>
#include <metal_logging>

using namespace metal;

[[stitchable]] float2 wave(float2 pos, float t) {
    os_log_default.log("SOMELOG");
    pos.y += sin(t * 5 + pos.y / 20) * 5;
    return pos;
}

And getting error "precondition failure: pipeline error: custom_effect-oQAAALAAAABQ9BMA: Encountered unlowered function call to air.os_log"
Metal version 3.2
EDIT:
My view:
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var start = Date.now

    var body: some View {
         TimelineView(.animation) { tl in
             let time = start.distance(to: tl.date)
             Image(systemName: "figure.walk.circle")
                 .font(.system(size: 100))
                 .background(.white)
                 .drawingGroup()
                 .distortionEffect(
                    ShaderLibrary.wave(
                        .float(time)
                    ),
                    maxSampleOffset: .zero
                  )
        }
    }
}

This is how i add flag:


Have you updated both xcode and the OS?

@Spo1ler
OS - macOS Sonoma 14.5 (23F79)
Xcode - Version 16.0 beta (16A5171c)

You can’t do that. So I’m doesn’t contain any code for os_log in Metal

@Spo1ler How so, then what is chapter 6.16 in the specification about ?

It's a new feature that's only available on Sequoia

@Spo1ler Thanks, updated the OS, now the error message is gone, but no logs in the logs or in the console application

We would need to see some code to understand what's going on
